# i want to show category wise product and paginate

Tags: python, django

I want to show category wise product and must be in paginate but its not working . i try to do this but I don't know why its not working. Here I have allProducts variable I tried to assign the paginate class but I think I am doing this in correct way maybe but its now working please give me solution for this

Here is my Views.py

```
def get(self, request):

        cart = request.session.get('cart')

        if not cart:
            request.session['cart'] = {}

        #products = None
        
        
        products = Product.objects.all()
        catsProduct = Product.objects.values("category")
        cats = {item["category"] for item in catsProduct}

        allProducts = []
        for cat in cats:
            prods = Product.objects.filter(category=cat)
            allProducts.append(prods)
            
        
        
        allProducts = Product.get_all_products()
        paginator = Paginator(allProducts, 12)
        page_number = request.GET.get('page')
        allProducts = paginator.get_page(page_number)
        
        cats = Category.get_categories()
        brands = Brand.get_brands()
        sliders = Slider.objects.all()
        offers = Offer.objects.all()

        categoryID = request.GET.get('category')
        brandID = request.GET.get('brand')

        if categoryID:
            # products = Product.get_products_by_category(categoryID)
            products = products.filter(category__id=categoryID)

        # else:
        #   products = Product.get_all_products()

        if brandID:
            # proucts = Product.get_brands_by_products(brandID)
            products = products.filter(brand__id=brandID)

        # else:
        #   products = Product.get_all_products()

        # print(request.session['customer'])

        args = {
            'products': products,
            'cats': cats,
            'brands': brands,
            'sliders': sliders,
            'offers': offers,
            'allProducts':allProducts
        }
        return render(request, 'Home/index.html', args)
```

Answer (score 0):

Django already gives you facility of pagination. You can check this out for pagination [django pagination](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/pagination/)

I will suggest you to use class based views and inherit that view with ListView,

Now in your get_context_data method get the queryset that you want to render on template and render them using django paginator. Here is how I implemented this.

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from django.core.paginator import EmptyPage
from django.core.paginator import PageNotAnInteger

class ApplyTasksListView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPorfileExistsMixin, 
      UserPorfileIsApprovedMixin, UserPorfileActiveMixin,
                         ListView):
    template_name = 'freelancer/eligible_tasks.html'
    model = Task
    paginate_by = 10

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ApplyTasksListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    curr_user = self.request.user
    now = timezone.now()
    task = Task.objects.filter(freelancer_assigned=None, deadline__gte=now).exclude(
        applied_by=curr_user).order_by('created_at').distinct()
    paginator = Paginator(task, self.paginate_by)

    page = self.request.GET.get('page')

    try:
        task_qs = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        task_qs = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        task_qs = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context['task_qs'] = task_qs
    return context
```

Comment: there is some indentation problem write the get_context_data method inside the class